# What does this sign on Air Tahiti ferry mean?

Tags: france, ferries, seating, accessibility

I saw this sign on Air Tahiti ferry in French Polynesia. What does the last icon on this place réservée sign mean? [image: place réservée sign]

Comment: It's a warning to let French Polynesia be your last battlefield.

Answer (score 17):

The seat is reserved for people with disabilities. The images are designed to show:

- Someone in a wheelchair
- A hearing aid (someone hard of hearing)
- Someone who is blind or partially sighted
- **The S3A pictogram** - a symbol designed to show that a place is open, including and able to facilitate people with disabilities. More information can be found at: http://www.supermanproject.eu/en/simbolo-di-accessibilita/

In general I noticed that exactly how different disabilities are shown changes and there isn't much of a standard. You can view some more examples at: https://oae.stanford.edu/resources-faqs/disability-access-symbols

Comment: The question is specifically about the last one.

Comment: Sorry, so it is, after a bit more googling I was able to find it.

Comment: The site says that the S3A pictogram specifically indicates accessibility to people with **mental** disabilities.  That's an important detail, I think.

Comment: That would *never* have occurred to me.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

To expand on the above response, as linked to the [SuperMAN site](http://www.supermanproject.eu/en/il-progetto-superman/), SuperMAN stands for SUPERmarkets Meet Accessibility Needs.

> On the 11th of February 2005 in France a law was passed on equal rights and opportunities, participation and citizenship of disabled. This law stated that the principle of accessibility is general regardless of the type of disability and that in 2015 in France all public places must be accessible.
>
> The S3A pictogram, created by the French association Unapei (national union of associations for parents and friends of people with mental disabilities) is the symbol of Welcome, Support and Accessibility.
>
> As there is an international symbol which indicates those places that are accessible to people with limited mobility, S3A pictogram has been created in order to easily localize places, services and products accessible to people with mental disabilities.
>
> For Unapei, the display of the S3A pictogram means undertaking tangible actions in favour of the accessibility and:
>
> - making an effort for everyone’s citizenship
> - being pioneers in the implementation of the French law
> - being able to adapt to the needs of people with mental disabilities, in order to offer them the right support
> - more in general, helping people with understanding, communication and time-and-space orientation difficulties.
>
> Unapei prepared the Practical guide on accessibility which outlines the actions to implement in order to make the access to places, services and products easier for people with mental disabilities and therefore to be entitled to display S3A pictogram.